# Списки переменных и функций

Tags: python

Допустим, что у меня есть список переменных:

```
var_list = [ alpha, beta, delta ]
```

А также список функций:

```
func_list = [ some_func(), another_func(), one_more_func() ]
```

Как написать код, который будет брать переменную из первого списка и давать значение соответствующей функции из второго списка? Чтобы это **не** выглядело так:

```
alpha = some_func()
beta = another_func()
delta = one_more_func()
```

Comment: Кажется, в коде изначально что-то пошло не так: Отдельные переменные в дальнейшем точно нужны? Можно ведь работать прямо с элементами списка (или словаря) вместо переменных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если переменные нужны глобальные, то как-то так:

```
var_list = [ 'alpha', 'beta', 'delta' ]
func_list = [ some_func(), another_func(), one_more_func() ]

for v,f in zip(var_list, func_list):
   globals()[v] = f
```

Без кавычек в первом списке ничего не выйдет, потому что в списке тогда будут **значения, содержащиеся в этих переменных**, и не будет никакой возможности этим переменным что-то обратно присвоить.

А в списке с функциями будут *результаты выполнения* функций, так как вы их вызываете. Но в вашем случае, я так понимаю, это несущественно - вызовутся функции сразу или в момент присвоения значений переменным.

Answer (score 3):

> `var_list = [ alpha, beta, delta ]`

В питоне нельзя присвоить значение значению переменной

> `func_list = [ some_func(), another_func(), one_more_func() ]`

Там вы создаете список не из функций, а **результатов** выполнения фукций!

Пусть будет так:

```
var_list = [ 'alpha', 'beta', 'delta' ]
func_list = [ 'some_func', 'another_func', 'one_more_func' ]
for v in var_list:
   exec(v+'='+func_list[var_list.index[v]]+'()')
```

А вообще это надо в словарь оборачивать:

```
key_list = ['alpha', 'beta', 'delta']
func_list = [some_func, another_func, one_more_func]
var_data = {}
for i in range(len(key_list)):
    var_data[key_list[i]] = func_list[i]()

print(var_data['beta'])
```